# Query parameter angular 10 with encrypted token

Tags: angular6, angular8, angular10

I am using query string using angular 10. I am sending token as parameter but it contain slashes and because of slashes it doesn't match the route. Here is my generated link

http://localhost: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

Here is my rout configuration

```
{path: 'setpassword/:token', component: SetpasswordComponent }
```

I want to fetch token like this but gives me nothing.

```
this.objModel.token = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('token')
```

Here is the code I am setting url

```
var url = _appSettings.EmailUrl+ token;
```

Comment: Can you please give us view from where you are setting this url up

Comment: url is basically generated and send via email where user can use it for further procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the problem is with slashes in your token which causes the problem. You need to encode the token and then send it as parameter.

```
var url = _appSettings.EmailUrl+ HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token);
```

This will helps remove slashes and put %2 sign instead. But when you use it you must decode this token to get back your token for further procedure.